# How to disable "Prevent the computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off" in MacBook Pro (M1) running macOS Ventura 13.0

Tags: macos, macbook, macbook-pro, macos-ventura

In the past, I enabled this in System Settings:

> “Prevent the computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off.”

Then I have updated macOS on the  MacBook Pro (M1) to Ventura 13.0 and cannot find this feature. Now I want to disable this feature but cannot find any way to do. Is there any solution?

Comment: What model MacBook Pro? Is it a newer Apple Silicon model? Because many power saving options line that are removed since Apple Silicon ARM-based processors are very power efficient.

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm using mac pro m1

Comment: I found the solution to this issue. It was in System Settings > Displays > Advanced > Prevent automatic sleeping on the power adapter when the display is off.

Comment: Odd. On my MacBook Air (M2; 2023) running macOS Sonoma (14.4.1 (23E224)) I don’t see that option at all under “System Settings > Displays > Advanced”: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUanZ.png